# Expresso Store/USPS plugin and multiple services/methods

Tags: expresso-store, shipping

I recently purchased the USPS plugin and wanted to know if it's possible to run more than one service (I'd like to offer priority or express to my customers) without using the "All" option.  Is this possible?

[image: The services options in the plugin settings]

Comment: I haven't used the USPS plugin since Store 2 came out but you might check Add-ons > Extensions > Store USPS page. From what I remember it had the ability to select some or all options.

Comment: I emailed the developer and they sent me an updated version of the USPS extension which they plan on releasing soon.  It has a multiple choice option along with international shipping options as well!  Thank you for your reply, Justin, and on another note, I've been building off of your expresso store articles on your website.  They've been a huge help!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad you were able to get it sorted out. I have been meaning to get back to the series with a fresh start for version 2 of Store but haven't had a chance to do it yet.

Answer (score 1):

I emailed the developer and they sent me an updated version of the USPS extension which they plan on releasing soon.  It has multiple choice options along with international shipping options as well.